# How can I copy my java program to another computer?

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote a simple java program to simulate a magic 8 ball and I figured my son would enjoy playing with it. I use Netbeans as my IDE but I want to be able to copy the program and put it on an old laptop that I let him use. The problem is I can't figure out how to copy the program and put it on a flash drive to copy it to his laptop.

I started learning C++ and stopped after the second semester and now I've decided to teach myself Java. In C++ I just had to save it as an .exe file and I could run it anywhere. I understand that java does things differently (although I don't fully understand that topic either) and I've seen other answers to a similar question but I wanted to know if there was a way I could load the program on to his computer where he doesn't need to compile and then run the program. Ideally all he'd need to do is click an icon on the desktop to launch the application.

I copied the code below if that helps. I apologize ahead of time as I have never posted a question here so I'm sure I've violated some sort of etiquette.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randInt = new Random();
    int num = randInt.nextInt(20) + 1;
    String input;
    char choice = 'n';
    boolean end = false;

    do{
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Ask me a question. I know all things.\nWhat is your question?");
        num = randInt.nextInt(20) + 1;

        switch (num){

            case 1 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Outlook is not good.");
                break;
            case 2 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer you're looking for is not in here.");
                break;    
            case 3 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most definitely yes.");
                break;    
            case 4 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is decidedly true.");
                break;
            case 5 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is certainly so.");
                break;
            case 6 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The stars tell me it is so.");
                break;
            case 7 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That's a stupid question. Pick another.");
                break;
            case 8 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer will come to you in time.");
                break;
            case 9 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yes - without a doubt.");
                break;
            case 10 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is a certainty written in prophecy.");
                break;
            case 11 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Chances are good.");
                break;
            case 12 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Most likely.");
                break;
            case 13 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Count on it.");
                break;
            case 14 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Play the lottery instead. There is a better chance of that happening.");
                break;
            case 15 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LOL! Absolutely not!");
                break;
            case 16 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a chance");
                break;
            case 17 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The stars are not aligned. No.");
                break;
            case 18 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I don't know. Try asking a Ouija board.");
                break;
            case 19 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It is so.");
                break;
            case 20 : 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'll get back to you on that.");
                break;
        }
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Would you like to ask another question? Y/N");
        choice = input.charAt(0);

            if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                end = true;                    
            }
            if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                end = false;
            }
            else{
                do{
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "I didn't understand. Would you like to ask another question?\nPlease enter\nY for yes\nor\nN for no");
                    choice = input.charAt (0);
                    if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                        end = true;                            
                    }
                    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                        end = false;
                    }
                }while (choice!='n'&& choice!='N'&&choice!='y'&&choice!='Y');
            }
    }while(!end);                       
}
```

Comment: export as runnable Jar with the main class set, copy the Jar file to the laptop, start the Program with `java -jar filename.jar` - indeed Java has to be installed on the Laptop

Comment: Alternatively, use [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) (`native-image`) to compile your Java program to an exe (note this is very much experimental).

Comment: No etiquette violated. This is a good post. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came back to StackOverflow looking for something else and realized I never really answered this question. For anyone that may be looking for this same thing I will post what worked for me (Using NetBeans IDE):

Go to Projects window (Ctrl + 1)
Find your project that you want to make in to a .jar and right click it
Properties>> Packaging>> check all three boxes and hit OK
Find your NetBeansProjects folder (default is in documents I believe)
YourProject>> dist

You should see your .jar file there.
I believe that you will need to include the lib folder as well if there is one in order to properly run the project

Answer (score 1):

You need JRE(Java runtime environment) to run the java programs. If you have JRE in your targeted machine then build the JAR file. Refer to the official [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). After that, you can run the jar file using the following command.

```
java -jar JarExample.jar
```

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: The poster requested that his son be able to double-click an icon to launch the app, as opposed to running a command.

Comment: if you are using windows, create a batch file to run the java program.